# Use dynamic variables in a constructor

Tags: variables, groovy, constructor

I have always those costA-costE and similar variables in different parts in my code and I was interested how I could make this easier/faster with some "Groovy Magic":

```
def class Test{

    int costA
    int costB
    int costC
    int costD
    int costE

    Test(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E)
    {
        ['A'..'E'].flatten().each
        {
             (this."cost${it}"="${it}") //does not work as expected
        }
    }

}

​Test test = new Test(1,2,3,4,5) ​​​​​​

['A'..'E'​​​​​​​​​].flatten().each​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​{​​println(test."cost${it}")}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Results to:

```
65  // 'A' etc.
66
67
68
69
70
```

The first part of it works, so something like this would be ok

```
 this."cost${it}"=1
```

But `"${it}"` just translates to A etc. instead of the value that is in A. `this."${it}"` would give me the wrong variable obviously, but how can I convince groovy to use the value that the constructor was given?

(I tried `args."${it}"` or `args[0]` etc. but it didn't work)

Bonusquestion (but not as important): Why do I need to flatten `['A'..'E']` to get a list with those 5 chars? Aka would there be a cleaner/shorter way to get the same list?

Comment: For what I can see, you may be modeling your object in the wrong way. You may wanna take a look on data structure concepts. Also could you tell what this code should do?

Comment: To store the costs of an element. Sometimes I need all the costs and sometimes I only need one of the 5 costs. But I have similar variables in other classes how many of each element they possess etc.

I know I could basically also do this in a map or even an array (because as long as I keep the right order the name is not important) but I was curious because the ${} syntax is there and I see no reason why the variables of the constructor shouldn't be accessible by this syntax as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not how the language works. But I believe the feature you are trying to implement can be modeled in another way. I'll post one way to go, but I strongly recommend that you try a different approach. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using lists (http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html) is the best way to go:

So you can have your class as:

```
class Cost {

    def amount
    def description

    def asString() {
        description + ': $' + amount // returns 'potatoes: $1.00'
    }

}

class CostsReport {

    List<Cost> costs

    def report() {
        costs.each { c -> println(c.asString() + '\n') } // prints out all your costs
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

**Map**

```
def map = [costA:50, costB: 60, costC: 70, costD: 80, costE: 90]
map.collect{k, v -> println " ${k} is ${v}"}
```

or ***Expand* Dynamic Bean**

```
def map = new Expando(costA:50, costB: 60, costC: 70, costD: 80, costE: 90)
map.properties.collect { k, v -> println "${k} is ${v}" }
```